# Oracle time stamp subtraction

Tags: oracle, datetime, timestamp

I have two time stamps in an oracle database I am trying to subtract but one is format “6/26/2023 2:20:35 PM” and one just the time “14:20:42”.  I found with trunc I can remove the time stamp but cannot find a way to remove the date so I can subtract the times.

I tried to time_stamp and trunc.  I would like to convert “6/26/2023 2:20:35 PM” to “14:20:35” in a format in can subtract against another time stamp.

Comment: Sounds like your second timestamp isn't stored as a timestamp data type. Is either, or are they both text? You need to convert it (them?) to proper date or timestamp types by *adding* a date component with `to_timestamp` or `to_date` so that Oracle can calculate the interval automatically, not by removing the date from the first. Otherwise how do you account for an interval that crosses midnight, or that is longer than 24 hours?

Comment: Ah, thank you.  Just did that and think I am in the ballpark.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `TIMESTAMP` and and `INTERVAL DAY(0) TO SECOND(0)` data types:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (
  col1 TIMESTAMP,
  col2 INTERVAL DAY(0) TO SECOND(0)
);

INSERT INTO table_name (col1, col2)
VALUES (TIMESTAMP '2023-06-26 14:20:35', INTERVAL '14:20:42' HOUR TO SECOND);
```

Then you can use:

```sql
SELECT col1,
       col2,
       col1 - col2
FROM   table_name;
```

Which, outputs:

| COL1 | COL2 | COL1-COL2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-06-26 14:20:35.000000 | +0 14:20:42 | 2023-06-25 23:59:53.000000000 |

*Note: A `TIMESTAMP` is a binary data-type consisting of 7 bytes representing century, year-of-century, month, day, hour, minute, second and zero-to-six bytes representing fractional seconds. It **ALWAYS** has those components and it is **NEVER** stored in any particular format. What you see when it is displayed is the formatting applied by the client application (for SQL*Plus and SQL Developer, then the default format used by the client application is the `NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT` session parameter, other clients will use their own settings).*

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/03jqmfXi)